503 Headers already sent
We have a site running v3.7 that hasen't been changed in more than a year.
It has now stopped working, and the server responds with a
503 craft\web\ServiceUnavailableHttpException
Yii Framework/2.0.45
Fatal error: Uncaught yii\web\HeadersAlreadySentException: Headers already sent 
in /home/spandend/anne-marie.nu/app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Response.php on line 433. 
in /home/spandend/anne-marie.nu/app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Response.php:368 Stack trace: #0 /home/spandend/anne-marie.nu/app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Response.php(341): yii\web\Response->sendHeaders() 
#1 /home/spandend/anne-marie.nu/app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/ErrorHandler.php(136): yii\web\Response->send() 
#2 /home/spandend/anne-marie.nu/app/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/ErrorHandler.php(192): yii\web\ErrorHandler->renderException(Object(yii\base\ErrorException)) 
#3 /home/spandend/anne-marie.nu/app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/ErrorHandler.php(288): craft\web\ErrorHandler->renderException(Object(yii\base\ErrorException)) 
#4 [internal function]: yii\base\ErrorHandler->handleFatalError() 
#5 {main} thrown in /home/spandend/anne-marie.nu/app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Response.php on line 368

It seems like it's trying to run an install process.

Our hosting provider states that they didn't update the servers.
We're pretty desparate, as we have a business that is depends on that web site.
Any help appreciated :pray:

It looks like Craft isn't able to connect to your database. I'd double-check the database credentials – you might have them in your config/db.php file, or as CRAFT_DB_ variables in your .env file.

Thank you so much, seems my hosting provider had migrated my database, which I had somehow missed.
